# IntentFilter won't work over regular String

Tags: android, regex, string, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I've been looking into this quite a time already and I haven't found an answer yet, so the thing is that currently on one of my activities I'm applying a coded intentFilter like this:

> filter = new IntentFilter(this.getResources().getString(
>                   R.string.download_action_intent));
>           try {
>               filter.addDataType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
>           }
>           catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
>               // TODO
>           }
>           filter.addDataPath(md5String, PatternMatcher.PATTERN_LITERAL);

The application is downloading a lot of images, this images are being downloaded by a Thread and they get to the activity through a BroadcastReciever, this particular activity only needs to get the downloaded image which corresponds to that md5String, so I set this filter to the broadcastReciever of this activity.

But even with the type and datapath I keep recieving every image the app downloads, how should I configure the IntentFilter so it only gets the call of that broadcasted md5String image??.

The broadcast send is like this:

> public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
>           String md5String = (String) msg.obj;
>           Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(
>                   this.mContext.getResources().getString(
>                           R.string.download_action_intent));
>           broadcastIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(md5String), HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
>           this.mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
>           return true;
>       }

thanks for your help and I hope I was clear enough, it's my first question here.

Comment: Are you using a built-in regex, or do you need a regex?

Comment: neither, I'm trying more to filter by the whole string (md5String) as i only need the downloaded file with that name.

Comment: Sorry, wish I knew more about it.

Comment: Well I know it's not very good explaine, so putting it simple, what I need is an intentfilter that will filter everything different to the specific string added to the dataPath.